# Python retain maximal integer from list

Tags: python, list

I have a list of integers composed by three digits each

```
list1 = [505, 504, 503, 502, 207, 206]
```

If we define a subset as all values classified by their first digit, I want to compare elements in list and retain the maximum one from each subset.

So for instance, here, subsets would be `[505, 504, 503, 502]` and `[207, 206]`.

The resulting `list` of max values from each subset would then be

```
max_values = [505, 207]
```

How can I go directly from `list1` to `max_values` ?

Comment: There must be a rule.Like numbers starting with 5 or 2 or etc.This isn't a clear question. It can be everything in that list, what is your rules? What is the range of numbers?

Comment: what is set in a list ?

Comment: @sasha http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27713046/number-of-triangles-containing-the-point-0-0/27713202#27713202 this is the best answer I have ever seen. +1!

Comment: Hi they are gene ids which i obtain from a different file. In the above 505 represents the original gene while other 504,503,502 are duplicates . same in case of 207. There is no order or range for these numbers.

Comment: Looks like your problem is more like a clustering problem where you want to keep the maximum element of each cluster. My question is: are the elements of each cluster going to be differentiated only by the top decimal digit?

Comment: @LordHenryWotton Yes, they are diferentiated by the top decimal digit and i want to retain such decimals from the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming there is a common first digit in the groups:

```
list1 = [505,504,503,502,207,206]

from itertools import groupby

for k,v in groupby(list1,key=lambda x: str(x)[0]): # use x // 100 if you only have three digit numbers
    print(max(v))

505
207
```

`groupby` groups all the elements using the key `str(x)[0]` which is the first digit of all the numbers in the list, then just we call max on the each grouping `v`.

Comment: Great !! This works . This forum is really awesome :-) . Thanks a lot Padraic. It would be nice if you can spend some time explaining your code. I am new to python so that i'll understand better. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I was thinking of something but you beat me both in speed & simplicity :)

Comment: could also work with `key=lambda x: x//100`, depending of the constraints of the OP

Comment: @Jivan, yes True that would work also, there are more efficient ways but this is simple and easy.

Comment: Do note that this requires the input array to already be sorted according to the grouping function to be used.

Answer (score 1):

If I got your question correctly and elements from the same group may be scattered around the input:

```
>>> def get_group(number):
    return number // 100

>>> result = {}
>>> for element in list1:
    group = get_group(element)
    last_max = result.get(group)
    result[group] = element if last_max is None else max(element, last_max)

>>> result.values()
[207, 505]
```