# Algorithm to find if triangles formed by set of points contains origin or not and give total count as well?

Tags: algorithm

Input: `S = {p1, . . . , pn}`, `n` points on 2D plane each point is given by its x and y-coordinate.

For simplicity, we assume:

`The origin (0, 0) is NOT in S.
Any line L passing through (0, 0) contains at most one point in S.
No three points in S lie on the same line.`

If we pick any three points from S, we can form a triangle. So the total number of triangles  that can be formed this way is  Θ(n^3).

Some of these triangles contain (0, 0), some do not.

Problem: Calculate the number of triangles that contain (0, 0).

You may assume we have an O(1) time function `Test(pi, pj , pk)` that, given three points pi, pj , pk in S, returns 1, if the triangle formed by `{pi, pj , pk}` contains (0, 0), and returns 0 otherwise. It’s trivial to solve the problem in Θ(n^3) time (just enumerate and test all triangles).

Describe an algorithm for solving this problem with O(n log n) run time.

---

My analysis of the above problem leads to the following conclusion

There are 4 coordinates ( + ,+ ) , ( + ,- ) , ( -, - ), ( -, + ) { x and y coordinate > 0 or not }.

Let

- s1 = coordinate x < 0 and y > 0
- s2 = x > 0 , y > 0
- s3 = x < 0 , y < 0
- s4 = x > 0 , y < 0

Now we need to do the testing of points in between sets of the following combinations only

1. S1 S2 S3
2. S1 S1 S4
3. S2 S2 S3
4. S3 S3 S2
5. S1 S4 S4
6. S1 S3 S4
7. S1 S2 S4
8. S2 S3 S4

I now need to test the points in the above combination of sets only ( e.g. one point from s1 , one point from s2 and one point from s3 < first combinaton > ) and see the points contain (0,0) by calling Test function ( which is assumed as constant time function here) .

Can someone guide me on this ?

Image added below for clarification on why only some subsets (s1,s2 , s4 ) can contain (0,0) and some ( s1,s1,s3) cannot.

[image: The quadrants s1,s2,s3 and s4]

Comment: ... Where do the '4 coordinates' `s1`...`s4` come from?  What is there roll in the problem?

Comment: s1 , s2 , s3 and s4 are the 4 divisions of coordinate system . they are just representations of the areas of x-y coordinate system dependent on what is the value of x and y are. E.g. s1 denotes the area in x-y coordinate system, where x < 0 and y > 0.

Comment: My assumption here is that for a point set p1, p2, and p3 to "enclose" origin within its triangle, they need to be either in s1...s4 . Thus the 6 combinations I wrote in my logic above is the combo , in which points ( if they form a triangle ) can possible enclose origin within it.

Comment: Okay, I see.  But note that this is a *necessary* but not a *sufficient* condition to enclose `(0,0)`.

Comment: Yes, that is why the required sets are tested recursively to check whether they do in fact contain `(0,0)` or not.

Comment: 1. Your list of allowed quadrant sets isn't complete, because it's OK for 2 points to come from the same quadrant if the third comes from the diagonally opposite one (you list s1 s1 s4, but not the other 3 possibilities).  2. Doing this might reduce runtime, but it doesn't change the time complexity -- there could be n/4 points in each quadrant.  3. I don't understand what "respective set combination are recursively divided" means, and I don't see how any kind of recursive subdivision can work here -- please explain further.

Comment: My first impulse with geometric problems is to see whether Convex Hull can be applied somehow.  Here, this would easily answer a slightly simpler question ("Does any triangle contain the origin?") -- if the Convex Hull contains the origin, then some triangle of points must.  You might be able to adapt one of the CH algorithms to perform counting.

Comment: @j_random_hacker : diagram added for clarity. I dont see how Convex hull can be applied here.

Comment: What about points like (3,0) that could be in S? While the origin isn't in the set, there could be points along either axis, no?

Comment: @JBKing : That condition will not occur as per problem statement "Any line L passing through (0, 0) contains at most one point in S."

Comment: What is the other line besides y=0 that contains both (0,0) and (3,0)?

Comment: How does  "Any line L passing through (0, 0) contains at most one point in S." prove that (3,0) can't be in S? The origin isn't in S and thus there could be a point along each axis in the set unless there is something else here that I'm missing.

Comment: @JBKing : Please read OP, the statement i paraphrased is stated as in the given problem. Clear now  ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93191/discussion-between-jb-king-and-cyprus).

Comment: The diagram is generally helpful, but you haven't updated your list of allowed quadrant sets to make it complete, and you haven't explained how the recursion is supposed to help.

Comment: Also: Do you only need to know *if* some triangle contains the origin (as your question title says), or do you actually need the exact count of triangles that do?

Comment: question updated. I need to find the total count

Comment: A quick, perhaps incorrect thought is that there's a sweep line algorithm where the line extends from and is swept about the origin.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm guessing we're in the same class (based on the strange wording of the question), so now that the due date is past, I feel alright giving out my solution. I managed to find the **n log n** algorithm, which, as the question stated, is more a matter of cleverly transforming the problem, and less of a Dynamic Programming / DaC solution.

**Note: This is not an exhaustive proof, I leave that to you.**

---

First, some visual observations. Take some triangle that obviously contains the origin.

[image: Triangle Containing Origin]

Then, convert the points to vectors.

[image: Vectors of Triangle]

Convince yourself that any selection of three points, one from each vector, describes a triangle that also contains the origin.

[image: Triangles from Origin]

It also follows that, if you perform the above steps on a triangle that doesn't enclose the origin, any combination of points along those vectors will also not contain the origin.

The main point to get from this is, **the magnitude of the vector does not matter, only the direction.** Additionally, a hint to the question says that "*any line crossing (0,0) only contains one point in S*", from which we can extrapolate that the direction of each vector is **unique.**

---

So, if only the angle matters, it would follow that there is some logic that determines what range of points, given two points, could possibly form a triangle that encloses the origin. For simplicity, we'll assume we've taken all the points in S and converted them to vectors, then normalized them, effectively making all points lie on the unit circle.

So, take two points along this circle.

[image: Normalized vectors form points along the unit circle.]

Then, draw a line from each point through the origin and to the opposite side of the circle.

[image: The red arc defines all possible points that can form a triangle with the two points.]

It follows that, given the two points, any point that lies along the red arc can form a triangle.

---

So our algorithm should do the following:

1. Take each point in S. Make a secondary array A, and for each point, add the angle along the unit circle (atan2(x,y)) to A (0 ≤ Ai ≤ 2π). Let's assume this is **O(n)**
2. Sort A by increasing. **O(n log n)**, assuming we use Merge Sort.
3. Count the number of triangles possible for each pair (Ai,Aj). This means that we count the number of Ai + π ≤ Ak ≤ Aj + π. Since the array is sorted, we can use a Binary Search to find the indices of Ai + π and Aj + π, which is **O(2 log n) = O(log n)**

However, we run into a problem, there are n^2 points, and if we have to do an **O(log n)** search for each, we have **O(n^2 log n)**. So, we need to make one more observation.

Given some Ai < Aj, we'll say Tij describes the number of triangles possible, as calculated by the above method. Then, given a third Ak > Aj, we know that Tij ≤ Tik, as the number of points between Ai + π and Ak + π must be at least as many as there are betwen Ai + π and Aj + π. In fact, it is exactly the count between Ai + π and Aj + π, plus the count between Aj + π and Ak + π. Since we already know the count between Ai + π and Aj + π, we don't need to recalculate it - we only need to calculate the number between Aj + π and Ak + π, then add the previous count. It follows that:

A(n) = count(A(n),A(n-1)) + count(A(n-1),A(n-2)) + ... + count(A(1),A(0))

And this means we don't need to check all n^2 pairs, we only need to check consecutive pairs - so, only n-1.

---

So, all the above can give us the following psuedocode solution.

```
int triangleCount(point P[],int n)
    int A[n], C[n], totalCount = 0;  

    for(i=0...n)
        A[i] = atan2(P[i].x,P[i].y);

    mergeSort(A);

    int midPoint = binarySearch(A,π);

    for(i=0...midPoint-1)
        int left = A[i] + π, right = A[i+1] + π;
        C[i] = binarySearch(a,right) - binarySearch(a,left);
        for(j=0...i)
            totalCount += C[j]

return totalCount;
```

Comment: I think you can apply Convex hull algorithm to determine whether the initial set of points contain (0,0) or not. It takes nlogn time, and can reduce algorithm time ( not asymptotic) when all points fail to form triangles containing origin

Comment: This is a really late response to this, but the problem stated that (0,0) was not in the origin. Otherwise, you'd be correct.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in the worst case there are Θ(n<sup>3</sup>) triangles containing the origin, and since you need them all, the answer is no, there is no better algorithm.

For a worst case consider a regular polygon of an odd degree `n`, centered at the origin.

Here is an outline of the calculations. A chord connecting two vertices which are `k < n/2` vertices apart is a base for Θ(k) triangles. Fix a vertex; its contribution is a sum over all chords coming from it, yielding Θ(n<sup>2</sup>), and a total (a contribution of all `n` vertices) is Θ(n<sup>3</sup>) (each triangle is counted 3 times, which doesn't affect the asymptotic).

Comment: There are indeed Theta(n^3) triangles in the worst case, but it doesn't follow that you necessarily need constant time (even on average) to count each one.  There might be some structure to the set of satisfying triangles that lets us count them faster.

Comment: @j_random_hacker I don't follow. Just to visit them takes  Θ(n3) time.

Comment: Clearly there DOES exists a nlogn time algorithm ( otherwise why  will the question even exist ? ) . Somehow there exists a method by which we need to visit only nlogn points.

Comment: @CyprUS I have a strong feeling that the problem is actually about finding _some_ triangle (it is doable linearithmically). Finding _all_ of them is cubic.

Comment: Nope , I re-read the problem given again. It specifies "count" all triangles containing (0,0). Maybe there is some trick to do here, by which we can count, and not need to check them explicitly.

Comment: @user58697: By way of analogy, there are lots of ways of choosing 10 objects from a set of 100 objects, but we can count them without having to enumerate all of them.  The same could be true here (though the structure isn't obvious).

Comment: @CyprUS: The fact that the question asker thinks an O(n log n)-time algorithm exists isn't proof of anything -- stupid questions exist.  Also PLEASE fix the other points I made in my comments on your question -- otherwise I'll -1.

Comment: @j_random_hacker : what points to fix ? Can you point it out ? And the question is given by my professor. So I don't think it is a stupid one :)

Comment: @CyprUS: Points 1 and 3 in my first comment -- which I mentioned again in my third comment!

Comment: Is it possible to do it in O(n2)?

Comment: @prasanth : consult this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27713046/number-of-triangles-containing-the-point-0-0?rq=1

Comment: I went through that link. But using Test(p1,p2,p3), can we do it in O(n2) time?

Comment: @prasanth : why not ? The algorithm written divides the set of points into x[] and y[] and does n^2 test on them to find possible candidates of points. Correct me if I am wrong here.

Comment: @CyprUS : You are right. But the problem mentions that we need to use Test(p1,p2,p3) not cross product.

Comment: @prasanth : The main idea to reduce time complexity from n^3 to n^2 is to reduce the number of times you have to call Test function. If you call Test function n^3 times, you have n^3 complexity. The link gives a way to reduce that comparison to n^2. By the way, no where in the question it is required to "use" Test. you are free to do it your own way.

Comment: @CyprUS: Despite all my prodding, you *still* haven't responded to point 1 from my 1st comment.  I quote: "you list s1 s1 s4, but not the other 3 possibilities".  -1.

Comment: @j_random_hacker : It is not easy to draw combination for all the 8 quadrant sets, nor do I have the patience. It is an intuitive thing, and certainly can be drawn by people who want to solve it themselves.